# Rendered more hooks than during the previous render when using hooks in subcomponent

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to understand how I can use React Hooks in subcomponents without triggering an error.

Let's say I have a super simple component (all the code is runnable here - https://codesandbox.io/embed/xenodochial-wright-mwqlk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark):

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestComponent = (index) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("nothing");

  useEffect(() => {
    setA(index);
  }, [setA, index]);

  return <>{a}</>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

And it is used like this:

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Component from "./Component";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArr([1]);
  }, []);

  const component = arr.map((_, index) => Component(index));

  return <div>{component}</div>;
}
```

Now I am getting an error:

```
Error
Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
▶ 5 stack frames were collapsed.
TestComponent
/src/Component.js:4:29
  1 | import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  2 | 
  3 | const TestComponent = (index) => {
> 4 |   const [a, setA] = useState("nothing");
    |                             ^
  5 | 
  6 |   useEffect(() => {
  7 |     setA(index);
```

There are more details in the console:

```
Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by App. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks

   Previous render            Next render
   ------------------------------------------------------
1. useState                   useState
2. useEffect                  useEffect
3. undefined                  useState
   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    at App (https://mwqlk.csb.app/src/App.js:24:41)
```

I understand the basic concept of the hooks rules that I cannot use hooks after `if` statements or such, they should always be on the top level.

However, this case is clearly not using any conditionals for declaring the hooks. All additional hooks are actually in a subcomponent. So why are they accounted for by React as part of the App component?

So, how can I safely use hooks in imported subcomponents then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling your react component like a function instead of using it as a component.  This causes some weirdness with rendering.  If you change your `.map` line to

```
const component = arr.map((_, index) => <Component index={index} />);
```

and destructure your props appropriately in `Component`

```
const TestComponent = ({ index }) => {
```

everything works as expected.

Comment: Darn it, I used it incorrectly indeed :) I upvoted all answers, but having this one as accepted because you spelled out what exactly was not working instead of simply providing an anwer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you should pass

App.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Component from "./Component";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArr([10,12,12,12,12]);
  }, []);

  return <>{arr.map((_, index) => (
    <Component key={index} index={index}/>
  ))}</>
}
```

Test component:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestComponent = ({index}) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setA(index);
  }, []);

  return <>{a}</>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You should refactor in this way

Component.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const TestComponent = ({index}) => {
  const [a, setA] = useState("nothing");

  useEffect(() => {
    setA(index);
  }, [setA, index]);

  return <>{a}</>;
};

export default TestComponent;
```

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import TestComponent from "./Component";

export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setArr([1]);
  }, []);

  const component = arr.map((_, index) => <TestComponent index={index}/>);

  return <div>{component}</div>;
}
```